# Asymptotic large order approximation for Bessel function expression

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

How does one find the asymptotic large order approximation for $\sup_{0\le x\le\infty} \left(\sqrt{x} J_n(x)\right)$, where $J_n$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and order $n$.  This is NOT a problem of large argument expansion.

I have tried to using all of the standard recursion relations, integral and series representations, etc. with little success.  For example, the usual large order asymptotic expressions provide little insight here inasmuch as we are searching for the asymptotic, large-order behavior of the supremum of $\sqrt{x}J_n(x)$ over all real, non-negative $x$.

Note:
I suspect that the answer might be $O(n^{\frac16})$ through, dare I admit it, empirical experiment.  But this "result" is not substantiated.  Any useful hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your numerical work, did you find that (for large $n$) the maximum value of $\sqrt{x}J_n(x)$ occurs near the first maximum of $J_n(x)$ or near some later maximum? In Watson's Treatise on the theory of Bessel Functions (Camb Press, 1944) he discusses "approximation by tangents, which works for large values of the index where the argument is *less than* the index. If the argument is greater than the index, Watson's formula 271 can be applied. But I suspect the maximum occurs when they are roughly equal, in which case formulas in Gradshteyn and Rhyzhik 8.454 apply. All the above are too scary.

Comment: @Mark Fischler Thanks!  And great first name.  The numerical work that I did was 25 years ago (yes, I have waited a long time to ask this) and I embedded this supposition in a refereed journal article.  If I recall correctly, the global maxima do occur at the first maxima.  I cannot recall whether the maxima occur at values less than the index.  Is Watson's work readily available?

Comment: I don't imagine it is readily available; certainly not in electronic form. I remember browsing it in 1972 at the MIT library. BTW, the sup value must occur just *past* the first maximum of $j_n(x)$ because $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing.

Comment: @MarkFischler Thanks.  And yes, if the max of $J_n$ is at point $x>1$, which I believe all of them are.

Comment: Watson's book can be found here: https://archive.org/details/ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions , although don't ask me about any possible legal issues...

Comment: And Watson's book will have expressions for the maxima of $J_n$?

Comment: I suspect that that the maximum occurs around the turning point where $n=x$. Asymptotically $$
\sqrt {n + an^{1/3} } J_n (n + an^{1/3} ) \sim (4n)^{1/6} {\mathop{\rm Ai}\nolimits} ( - 2^{1/3} a)
$$ for large $n$ and bounded $a$, where $\mathrm{Ai}$ is the Airy function. If $a'_1$ denotes the first negative zero of $\mathrm{Ai}'$ then $$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x > 0} \sqrt x J_n (x) \sim (4n)^{1/6} {\rm Ai}( a'_1) \sim 0.67488509n^{1/6} .
$$

Comment: @Gary. I think that the maximum occurs just below $j_{n,1}$

Comment: @Gary I found this paper https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/ref/10.1080/10652460600643445?scroll=top&role=tab but I cannot access it

Comment: I found this paper https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/ref/10.1080/10652460600643445?scroll=top&role=tab but I cannot access it

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It accurs at about $
 \approx n + \frac{{\left| {a'} \right|_1 }}{{2^{1/3} }}n^{1/3}  \approx n + 0.8086165169n^{1/3} $ which is asymptotic to $j'_{n,1}$, the first zero of the derivative. I checked the paper and it proves my guess. There is an upper bound given there which is asymptotic to the approximation I provided above. I any case, the paper gives a detailed answer to Mark Viola's question.

Comment: @Gary. Good to know it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let $\nu>0$ and denote $c_\nu=\sup_{x\ge 0}\sqrt{x}|J_\nu(x)|$. It is shown in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1080/10652460600643445) that
$$
c_\nu \leq \frac{{\sqrt {j_{\nu ,1} } }}{{\nu ^{1/3} }}2^{1/3} \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} \left| \operatorname{Ai}(x) \right| = \frac{{\sqrt {j_{\nu ,1} } }}{{\nu ^{1/3} }} \times 0.67488509 \ldots ,
$$
where $j_{\nu,1}$ is the first positive zero of $J_\nu(x)$ and $\operatorname{Ai}(x)$ is the Airy function. It is also proved that
$$
c_\nu \sim 2^{1/3} \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} \left| \operatorname{Ai}(x) \right|\times \nu^{1/6} = 0.67488509 \ldots \times \nu^{1/6}
$$
as $\nu \to +\infty$. Since $j_{\nu,1}\sim \nu$, the above upper bound is asymptotically sharp.

Comment: Hi Gary.  So my conjecture from more than 30 years ago was correct.

Comment: (+1) for the posted answer